# How to sort CSV file by header?

Tags: perl, sorting, unix, csv

There are two **CSV files** I want to **compare**. However, they have **different order** of headers and rows/values.

Here's a simple example:

**INPUT FILE1:**

```
NAME,AGE,BDAY
ABC,1,090214
DEF,1,122514
```

**INPUT FILE2:**

```
BDAY,NAME,AGE
122514,DEF,1
090214,ABC,1
```

**INPUT FILE3:**

```
BDAY,NAME,AGE
122514,DEFG,1
090214,ABC,1
```

**Diff FILE1 and FILE2**

```
No diffs.
```

**Diff FILE1 and FILE3**

```
Found diffs in FILE and FILE3.

<Any format of diffs is okay.>
```

I can easily create a perl script for this but before I do, does anyone know if there's an existing script/tool that already does this?

I have tried copying the files from UNIX to Windows, and sorting them using Excel. It works well but I encounter problems saving it.

I also have googled but can't find a reference for this.

Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking: how to reorder? how to sort? indicate your desired output to make it clear. Hint: `awk` could make the job by toggling columns.

Comment: You can reorder the columns using AWK but you will need to specify the order `cat file1 | awk -F',' 'BEGIN{OFS = ",";}{ print $3,$1,$2}'`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle yes, good point. Note, though, there is no need to `cat`: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print ...}' file` makes it.

Comment: @fedorqui yeah you are correct. For some reason in unix i always cat, even into grep etc. just a bad habbit of mines

Comment: Thanks for the inputs fedorqui and ChrisDoyle. Will try them out!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need some kind of advanced comparation (with requires deeper analysis), so the use of a relational db approach maybe interesting. 
In this respect, the [module DBD::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::CSV) is helpful. It allows writting SELECT statements, including join between tables.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize your data

1. Use [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) to reorder the columns of your CSV file.
2. Then you can use Perl’s [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) or some other utility to reorder the rows of your files.

This also uses [`Text::Wrap`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Wrap.html) to display the normalized files in a pleasing format:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

# Setup fake data
my @files;
{
    local $/ = '';    # Paragraph mode
    while (<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        my ( $file, $data ) = split "\n", $_, 2;
        open my $fh, '>', $file;
        print $fh $data, "\n";
        push @files, $file;
    }
}

# Normalize Files by Column Order
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1, eol => $/ } )
    or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag();

for my $file (@files) {
    local @ARGV = $file;
    local $^I   = '.bak';
    my @old_order;
    my @new_order;
    while (<>) {
        if ( !$csv->parse($_) ) {
            die "Bad parse $file, line $.: " . $csv->error_diag();
        }

        my @columns = $csv->fields();

        if ( $. == 1 ) {
            @old_order = @columns;
            @new_order = sort @columns;
        }

        my %hash;
        @hash{@old_order} = @columns;

        if ( !$csv->combine( @hash{@new_order} ) ) {
            die "Bad combine $file, line $.: " . $csv->error_diag();
        }

        print $csv->string();
    }
    unlink "$file$^I";    # Optionally delete backup
}

# Normalize Files by Row Order
for my $file (@files) {
    my ( $header, @data ) = do { local @ARGV = $file; <> };
    open my $fh, '>', $file;
    print $fh $header, sort @data;
}

# View Normalized Files
use Text::Wrap;
for my $file (@files) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    print wrap( sprintf( "%-12s", $file ), ' ' x 12, <$fh>, ), "\n";
}

__DATA__
file1.csv
NAME,AGE,BDAY
ABC,1,090214
DEF,1,122514

file2.csv
BDAY,NAME,AGE
122514,DEF,1
090214,ABC,1

file3.csv
BDAY,NAME,AGE
122514,DEFG,1
090214,ABC,1
```

Outputs:

```
file1.csv   AGE,BDAY,NAME
            1,090214,ABC
            1,122514,DEF

file2.csv   AGE,BDAY,NAME
            1,090214,ABC
            1,122514,DEF

file3.csv   AGE,BDAY,NAME
            1,090214,ABC
            1,122514,DEFG
```